# MVC Partialview detail action is not rendered in to jquery modal dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

While click partial view details button, i would like to display the actionresult to jquery modal dialog, but it is not happening instead the result is displayed in next page. I tried the below way. 
please see the attached screen shot. I appreciate your help.

page is loaded with jquery-1.10.2.min.js, jquery-ui-1.11.4.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

1. defined in Main.cshtml
2. On page load on Ajaxcall Detailview1 is rendered with html result.
3. if click detail button, partialview is loaded in to another page not in modal dialog.

```js
function loadpartialview(pageurl) {
        //alert('loadpartialview ');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //url: pageurl,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPVAjaxCall", "VADV")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
                $("#DetailView1").empty();
                $("#DetailView1").html(result);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error in ajax call VADV.loadpartialview:' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

$(document).on('click', '.openDialog1', function () {
            alert('openDialog1 ' + this.href + '  ' + $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"));
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                height: 500,
                width: 1000,
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                modal: true
            })
            .load(this.href);
        });

$(function () {
  
  var url = "/VADV/GetPVAjaxCall";
        loadpartialview(url);
  });
```

```html
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="DetailView1"></div>

Partialview (GetPVAjaxCall.cshtml)
@model IEnumerable<VAMDEScheduler.Models.VADetailRecord>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VeteranName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DoctorName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimFileDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "VADV", new { id = item.Id },
            new { @class = "openDialog1", data_dialog_id = "result1", data_dialog_title = "Modal Title" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

[image]

Comment: You not cancelling the default redirect of your `<a>` element. Add `return false;` after the line `.load(this.href);` (`e.preventDefault();` does nothing because there is no `e`)

Comment: Alternatively, change it to `$(document).on('click', '.openDialog1', function(e) {`

Comment: Perfect Stephen.. working fine... thanks